# how to create a new column based on string from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe look like this:

| type | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dki jakarta |
| 2 | jawa barat |
| 3 | jawa tengah |
| 4 | jawa timur |
| 5 | sulawesi |

I want to create a new column called `city_group` based on the city.

- dki jakarta, jawa barat: jabo, jabar
- jawa tengah, jawa tengah: jateng, jatim
- sulawesi: others

The desire dataframe would be like this:

| type | city | city_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dki jakarta | jabo, jabar |
| 2 | jawa barat | jabo, jabar |
| 3 | jawa tengah | jateng, jatim |
| 4 | jawa timur | jateng, jatim |
| 5 | sulawesi | others |

So far, what I have done is with this script below but I did not get how to put multiple string in the condition.

```
df.loc[df['city'].str.contains("dki jakarta),'city_group'] = 'jabo, jabar'
```

How can I get the desired dataframe with pandas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create dictionary of lists for mapping by keys and in dict comprehenion flatten it, so possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) - all values not matched in dictionary create `others` values in column `city_group`:

```
d = {'jabo, jabar':['dki jakarta','jawa barat'],
     'jateng, jatim':['jawa tengah','jawa timur']}

d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
df['city_group'] = df['city'].map(d1).fillna('others')
print (df)
   type         city     city_group
0     1  dki jakarta    jabo, jabar
1     2   jawa barat    jabo, jabar
2     3  jawa tengah  jateng, jatim
3     4   jawa timur  jateng, jatim
4     5     sulawesi         others
```